# In-place multiplication subroutine - passing pointers or values?

Tags: c, signal-processing

I need to do a subroutine which multiplies two numbers and shifts the final result.

Which is a more proper subroutine:

```
void mul_inplace_both_pointers(q23* inout, q23* in)
{
    *inout = (*inout * *in);
    *inout = *inout << 8;
}
```

or

```
void mul_inplace_one_pointer(q23* inout, q23 in)
{
    *inout = (*inout * in);
    *inout = *inout << 8;
}
```

or

```
q23 mul_no_pointers(q23 in1, q23 in2)
{
    q23 out; 
    out = in1 * in2;
    out = out << 8;
    return out;
}
```

The code runs on a DSP processor, so it should be both speed and size optimized.

```
q23 a;
q23 b;

    mul_inplace_both_pointers( &a, &b);
    mul_inplace_one_pointer  ( &a,  b);
a = mul_inplace_no_pointers  (  a,  b);
```

For a minute I can omit speed and size requirement, and just ask what is the most proper from programmers point of view?

Comment: If it must be optimal, compile all three and profile. Have a look at the generated asm too. Using a function call for something trivial like this however will hurt execution time, unless it is inlined. It would be worth checking that.

Comment: What type`ae_q23` is `typedef`ed to ?

Comment: The last version looks much better (my opinion), if the ae_q23 type is an int (as I suspect) parameters would be probably passed on registers which is also probably the fastest version too.

Comment: Let's say `ae_q23` is `int`. It's a fixed point processor.

Comment: are these signed or unsigned, and is it possible they are narrower than `int` ?

Comment: I would default to `A mul(A a, A b) { return 256u * a * b; }`  . If you knew that overflow was not a problem you can remove the `u` (means undefined behaviour in case of overflow)

Comment: @M.M what would happen if one of the arguments is negative?

Comment: @KamiKaze I'd need to know more about the input preconditions before finalizing my answer :) Negative left-shift is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Input is a Q8.23 number, 32 bits, 1, sign, 8 integer, 23 fraction. `*` and `<<` are overloaded operators which end up as DSP assembly instructions for multiplication and shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I would minimise the number of pointers passed to a function as much as possible.   That would work out to only passing a pointer if (1)  the value of the argument (pointed to) needs to be changed   or (2) passing by value involves overhead that is significant in terms of working of your program (e.g. a very large data structure).

So, if you must use a function like your `mul_inplace_XXX()` style of function, I would probably choose the `mul_inplace_one_pointer()` function ...

In your particular case - depending on what `ae_q23` is, I wouldn't use a function at all.  I'd simply do

```
  inout *= in;
  inout <<= 8;
```

in the ostensible caller instead.   Or, subject to testing;

```
  inout = (inout * in) << 8;
```

Obviously I'm assuming none of the operations introduce undefined or otherwise (potentially) unintended behaviour.

In terms of performance, there are rarely any absolute guarantees though.   Test and profile, naturally, to be sure on your target platform.   Trying to optimise without testing/profiling is called "premature optimisation" for several reasons - most notably, that the code you lovingly hand-craft may not actually be optimal by your intended measures.